# Android: Not able to receive PACKAGE_REMOVED broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have my receiver code

```
    BroadcastReceiver pkgRemoveReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // do my stuff
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
    registerReceiver(pkgRemoveReceiver, filter);
```

So, whenever an app is removed from the device I get to do some book keeping. However, I am not able to receive the broadcast. Does the above code has any problem?

Thx!
Rahul.

Comment: By "whenever an app is removed from the device I get to do some book keeping" you mean your app or any app? PS: weak accept ratio.

Comment: Not my app. Any other app but not mine. Yes. I noticed the accept ratio. Will accept today.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: Have you made sure your app is still running? If it is not, then it will not receive the broadcast. You can specify your broadcast receivers in your manifest file if you wish to receive broadcast events while your app is closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try as:

```
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
   filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
   filter.addDataScheme("package"); // add addDataScheme
   registerReceiver(pkgRemoveReceiver, filter);

   BroadcastReceiver pkgRemoveReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // do my stuff
        if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED.equals(action)) {
             Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
    }
};
```